# Can an angular directive contain a controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Or perhaps a better question is, **should** a directive contain a controller?

For reasons of separation, my index.html is a simple file. Everything is rendered into it via templates. So my index.html is real simple:

```
<body ng-app="myapp"><mainmenu></mainmenu><div ng-view></div></body>
```

I don't really need a directive for `mainmenu`, but it allows me to put the menu in a separate template file. The main menu itself contains user info, login/logout, and a search box.

```
    <div class="leftmenu" ng-show="isLogin()">
    <ul class="menu"> 
        <li><a href="/part1">Part1</a></li> 
        <li><a href="/part2">Part2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="/part3">Part3</a></li> 
    </ul>

    <div ng-controller="Search" class="Search><input type="text" ui-select2="s2opts" style="width:250px;" ng-model="search" data-placeholder="search"></input></div>
</div>

<div class="rightmenu">
    <ul ng-show="isLogin()" class="menu">
        <li><a href="/account">My Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="/logout" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul ng-show="!isLogin()" class="menu">
        <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So there is the menu part, with its own controller, and the search, with its own, embedded between the two parts.

Of course, my `mainmenu` directive unit tests fail because `SearchController` isn't defined. But this leaves me wondering if I am going about this wrong. Should I even have it like this, a section of html with an explicit `ng-controller` defined inside it? Doesn't this create all sorts of weird dependencies?

How should I better structure this? A `search` directive that is included so I can unit test it separately? Something feels wrong here structurally...

UPDATE:

As requested, a basic fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nj4n44zx/1/

Comment: If I may, I would add a biased comment here. If you are talking about rendering template views etc, I would go with `angular.ui.router`. Awesome routing feature, awesome state controls. And it makes testing easier. Else, to me, directives are meant to be reusable. But still, your choice of design though.

Comment: Biased is good; at least it is something I can agree or disagree with. Unbiased is boring. :-) So, you may be right, I will take another look at angular.ui.router (since I use a lot of angular.ui anyways). But, I would like to resolve the core architectural question above either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified by the Angular documentation, the best practice is to define a controller inside a directive only to expose an API to another directive. Otherwise the link function is sufficient.

See at the bottom of :

[Angular directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

By experience using controllers inside a directives shadow what you are doing in your scope. It does not help to have a easy readable code.

I do prefer using the main controller where the directive is included. With a non isolated scope you have access to everything from the link function.

Comment: what you are saying makes sense. How would you refactor the above to have it make more sense? That is what I am struggling with?

Comment: Depending on what your are doing in your Search Controller... What I would to is to define a controller at the body level, upper that the directive. In other to have a place where doing logic that is accessible to the directive. Also important : logic concerning the search can be included in a service. Directive is not the only place for reuse. JSFiddle it, we will be able to give a complete implementation.

Comment: If you just want to isolate a template (the menu template), a ng-include is sufficient. Actually, it is very frequent to have the menu included by ng-include instead of a directive since it is not reused outside of the main app. See this plunker, it is just a copy of your fiddle done in this way : http://plnkr.co/edit/KGTs7PyUHMnzgw2fRFcK?p=catalogue

Comment: ha, I think you are right. This is a much better use case for `ng-include` instead of a directive. In the end, I worked it out by moving to the new `ui-select` directive, and then passing arguments into my mainmenu directive, but I could just as easily have done it your way (if I had thought of it then); it is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I usually deal with it like that:

```
app.directive('topMenu', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E', // or whatever You need
        templateUrl: '/partials/topmenu', //url to Your template file
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.foo = "bar";
        }
    };
});
```

Then, in that template You don't have to add ng-controller.

Comment: I think I wasn't very clear. There is the menu part, and then there is the search, which itself is a separate element with its own controller. I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

sure your directive can contain a controller because you declare a directive like this

```
myApp.directive('mainMenu', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'menu.html',
        controller:['$scope', function($scope) {
            //define your controller here
        }]
    };
});
```

Comment: I think I wasn't very clear. There is the menu part, and then there is the search, which itself is a separate element with its own controller. I edited the post.